# Defining fixed image doesn't affect it and makes it responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, background-position

I have the following rules in my css stylesheet:

```
body {
    background: url('../Pic/poly-parallax Half.png') fixed center no-repeat;
    background-color: rgb(231,231,231);
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: left;
}

.logo {
    height: 275px;
    background: url('Pic/Logo.png') fixed center no-repeat;
    background-size: 275px 70px;
    background-position: top right;
}
```

**But the logo image is keep on being responsive although i defined it as fixed.**

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BSC1.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Examples:

zoom 100%:
[image: zoom 100%:]

zoom 200%:
[image: zoom 200%:]

Comment: I don't see it being responsive, I tried it in a jsfiddle. What do you see happening as being responsive?

Comment: Zooming +/- resizing the logo while the body image is fixed

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2ukt6z7w/ I don't see any change in the image when resizing.

Comment: I use visual studio to code

Comment: Me too, but I linked an example of your code so you can see what I see.

Comment: Yes, and in your example you can clearly see that zooming in and out on the html page is resizing the logo (top right) image. I want it to be fixed image and never change its size even when i zooming in and out. The same way my background picture is working.

Comment: Responsiveness does not apply to "zooming" in browser, it refers to different screen sizes. Zooming images when zooming is an intended effect.

Comment: Still, how do i make the logo image to be fixed on screen and not changing it self while zooming as the background image reacts? For now, they are defined exactly the same.

Comment: The background isn't changing because an image behaves differently than a background image. When you zoom the image element is changing size but the body element isn't so it doesn't resize. You can set the logo to be an empty container and apply the image as background if you want them to behave the same.

Comment: OK, but how to write it over?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you might want to change is the `body`'s background-size from `contain` to `cover` to really fill the window (as I did below), but the logo does *not* change its size with those settings and always stays at the top right:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://placehold.it/1200x800/fa0') fixed center no-repeat;
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
}

.logo {
  height: 275px;
  background: url('https://placehold.it/275x70/a0f') fixed center no-repeat;
  background-size: 275px 70px;
  background-position: top right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="BSC1.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My image is fit exactly the way i defined it on the css. Changing it will ruin the resolution. As i wrote, the picture is fixed so it looks perfect as it has to be only on the left side of the screen.

Comment: The problem is only with the second picture (logo) which resizing itself while zooming in and out on the html page.

Comment: Well, zooming (in the browser) always means that *everything*  is zoomed - you can't change that. What's the problem about it?

Comment: You are wrong. You can define (as i did with the background image) it to be fixed and it will not resize itself even if you zoom in and out. It works perfectly with my background image.

Comment: What you define as `fixed` in your CSS is the fixed background-*background-attachment* (as opposed to scrolling along with the content), not the size.

Comment: So test it and see for yourself, it is not resizing while zooming in and out. Moreover, i defined it as the logo image and still, they react differently

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know what you mean (and it seems I am not the only one). Maybe you should create images of what you want and what you get at different zooming factors and add that to your question.

Comment: Added the images showing the % differences on the objects